# Mac terminal says: "Cannot open display...aborting"

Tags: macos, plot, terminal, display

When I'm using XFoil (for Mac, XQuartz installed) and I'm trying to plot something, the above message comes out. Another thing, I've used the instructions of the following link to install Gnuplot and I'm worried I did some damage... it's all ok with this?
http://macappstore.org/gnuplot/

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

within the shell, so GNUplot knows that it should use the standard display (i. e. your XQuartz environment)

Comment: not a useful method, it will reset DISPLAY variable to null. app like mupdf-gl cannot launched because fail to get $DISPLAY.

Answer (score 1):

On a MAC, install Xquartz and ensure it is running after your attempt to start your X application.

`pgrep -fl Xquartz` will show all the processes and their arguments that match `Xquartz`.

If you don't have pgrep, run `/bin/ps -o 'pid,command' -e | grep Xquartz` instead.

Look for the entry for the executable itself with the display set; something like this:

`1182 /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz :0 -nolisten tcp -iglx -auth ...`

The first number is the process id, or PID. If you wait 20-30 seconds and re-run the command, ensure the number is the same.

If the PID has changed, then you have the problem I ran into, where Xquartz is exiting with an error and the system is restarting it again, whenever I tried running xterm.

To check logs for an error, start the Console app found in /Applications/Utilities. In the search box, type `Xquartz` and press return, and you should see only the Xquartz entries.

The error log I saw was:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
   -: line 0: exec: uid=501(...): not found
```

After some investigation, I figured out that all I needed to do was set TERM prior to running the X server, and this can only be done in a `.x11run` file created in your home directory.

Create ~/.x11run with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TERM=xterm-256color
# include other vars the X11 server may need
/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin "${@}"
```

Then, make it executable: `chmod +x ~/.x11run`.

Next, log out (Apple icon top left, click Log Out), and then log back in, and try your app, in my case, xterm, and after several seconds, it finally appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an *xserver* first. On a MAC you would use [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org). You need to download and install XQuartz and from within XQuartz (right click on the logo after start) start a terminal. In this terminal navigate to the location where [xfoil](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) is installed and run it. The DISPLAY variable (as shown in another answer) is automatically preset in this terminal. So no need to do this if you run as described here.

For the installation of xfoil (macOS Catalina) I had to compile the code. I followed [these instructions](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/01/23/xfoil-mac-os-x/) which worked like a charm.